# Merge the tags "angry-birds" and "angry-birds-space"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Still going over the tags, I just stumbled upon [angry-birds](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angry-birds) (x13) and [angry-birds-space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angry-birds-space) (x2). I'd suggest to make the spacy chickens a synonym to their earth-bound companions.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In favor. Normally I would say different apps. but Angry Birds is Angry Birds. :)